# Getting information about configured (webservices.xml) web service handlers programatically

Tags: web-services, jax-rpc

In a Web Service, I have few GenericHandlers configured as server (Role) in webservices.xml (for IBM Runtime) & server-config.wsdd (Axis Runtime). Say the handlers are A, B & C.

Now, when there is an inbound call, A, B & C are getting invoked as expected.

I am basically looking for a way to know (programmatically) the number of handlers configured for this web service, i.e., 3 in this case, and a few other handler specific details.

I was investigating getting hold hold of HandlerChain by following way:

```
HandlerRegistry hndlReg = service.getHandlerRegistry();
List hChain = hndlReg.getHandlerChain(new QName("http://test.com","<<Port Name>>"));
```

but I don't get `hChain` to contain information about A,B or C. Ya, here I can add handlers programmatically which get invoked, too, but no information of already configured handlers in configuration files.

Is there any way (programmatically) to get the details about already configured handlers?

Appreciating your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to your webservices.xml? What about parsing it?

Comment: It is not accessible. The program could be a client application where the information is needed.